# How can I get multiple annotations defined by a user, that have the types of parameters expected in a constructor?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Let's say I have a **Course() constructor**, with parameters such as: **String name** and **int age**.

I would like the user to use annotations, specifying the parameters that the constructor, or method has.

Something like this:

```
@Param (param = String.class)
@Param (param = int.class)
public Course(String name, int age) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

So that later on, when I get the constructor, I can infer from the annotations what parameters I must use to get an instance of that class.

```
package DomainModel;

public @interface Param {
    Class<?> param();
    //ArrayList<Class<?>> params;
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Note that reflection already gives you the parameter types.

Comment: God no... It does? I'm gonna look into that right now. Btw, I forgot to mention. I have no ideia what Class type it is!! It might be anything.

Comment: Check out the `Method` and `Constructor` classes.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#getParameterTypes%28%29

Answer (score 0):

define your annotation like this...

```
 public @interface Param {
          String name();
          Integer age();
 }
```

then your user can use like this..

```
@Param (name="your_name", age=your_age)
public void setCourse(String name, int age) {


}
```

then you need reflection to assign your annotated value to your members.